# Typescript: how to do type narrowing in an object mapper?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object, where each value is a function that expects either a string, or array of strings:

```
const myMapper: Record<Filter, (value: string | string[]) => string> = {
  contains: (value: string) => `do something with ${value}`,
  between: ([value1, value2]: string[]) => `something with ${value1} and ${value2}`,
};
```

The problem: If I let ts know that the argument in the function can be either a string or an array, it will throw the error:

```
Type '(value: string) => string' is not assignable to type '(value: string | string[]) => string'
```

For the first item and a similar error for the second item.

How can I promise ts that I will know to pass the right type of value (string or array of strings) when using the object? Is the only option to use `unknown` for the second argument of Record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply omitting the explicit type annotation looks like it'd be enough, and is easier too.

```
const myMapper = {
  contains: (value: string) => `do something with ${value}`,
  between: ([value1, value2]: string[]) => `something with ${value1} and ${value2}`,
};
```

This way, you don't even need to "promise" that you'll pass the right type of argument - TypeScript will prevent you from passing the wrong argument in the first place `contains` will only accept a string, and `between` will only accept an array of strings).

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, it makes sense, but the problem is that I'd like to access this object dynamically, I don't know in advance which properties I'll access and when. When I try to access this dynamically without type annotation I'll get the error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & string[]' - if I try to pass a string as an argument.
Does it mean that my design is wrong?

Comment: You should check that the property being accessed and the arguments being passed match up when calling. `const propToCall: string = 'between';
const args: string | string[] = ['str1', 'str2'];
if (propToCall === 'contains' && typeof args === 'string') {
    myMapper[propToCall](args);
} else if (propToCall === 'between' && Array.isArray(args) && typeof args[0] === 'string') {
    myMapper[propToCall](args);
}`

Comment: Oh I see thank you very much! Another solution I thought of is to expect two arguments instead of one, then there will always be the first one, and instead of the property that expects an array of two items, it can use the second argument.